# Generics are not supported at language level '1.4'using Intellij & Java ME

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-me

I am using Java ME x IntelliJ for this project but I seem to be getting the `Generics are not supported at language level '1.4'` error for the below code block:

```java
AccessPoint accessPoint = AccessPoint.of("WIFI",
                                                    new ConnectionOption<String>("ssid", "Net-1-AT"),
                                                    new ConnectionOption<char[]>("password", new char[]{'a', 't'}));
// specifically at the <String> and <char[]> areas
```

My configuration:
[image]

Comment: You need to update your language settings in IntelliJ to a more recent Java version.  This is a common problem, by the way.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my Java ME version was downloaded yesterday from the oracle website so it should be up to date...

Comment: That's not the problem; IntelliJ is pointing to 1.4 in some places.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen do you know where I can change the places that are pointing to 1.4?

Comment: Try `SHIFT` + `CTRL` + `ALT` + `S`, then check your project module settings.

Answer (score 0):

Generics where introduced to Java with version 5 (in 2004), which corresponds to language level `1.5`. Unless you are working on a specific project where you are bound to level `1.5`, for some external reason, you should use a more recent version (8, 11 or 14) because they are more secure and have the feature you are looking for.

Comment: Where do I change this? From what I know the project language level is `8`...

Answer (score 0):

J2ME is basically unsupported and has no support for newer language features. Write the code without generics.